# Electric field cavity conductor

Tags: electromagnetism

[image]

According to the image, they say that the electric field inside a cavity with no charge in it must be zero, since the electric field inside the conductor is zero and the closed loop integral of E dot dl must be 0 also.

However, if there were a charge in the cavity, let's say a positive charge in the middle of the cavity, then clearly the electric field is not zero in the cavity, but using the same closed loop as in the image, then the closed loop integral of E dot dl is not zero?

How is this possible? If you use the same argument, the electric field would have to be 0 in the cavity, (since the electric field is 0 in the conductor), since the closed loop integral is always zero, but clearly the electric field inside the cavity can't be zero?

So how can there be an electric field inside the cavity if there's a charge in it, AND at the same time having the closed loop integral be zero in that case using the same loop?

Clearly the closed loop integral of E dot dl always has to be zero right? Since the curl of the electric field of a point charge is zero, so by superposition, the curl is always zero, and thus the closed loop integral also must be 0 always of the electric field.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer already, it is true that the closed loop integral of E dot dl is always zero, even if there is a charge inside the cavity, and also if there is no charge inside the cavity.